# Write to file instead of stdout

Tags: stdout

I am writing a program in C.This program prints out the files present in current directory.
I want the output in some text file not on the console.
my program is:-

```
int main()
{

        system("ls");
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well one way is while executing in the terminal just do `./xyz > logfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `system()`, and this is already platform-dependent, just use the shell's redirection capability -- i.e.,

```
system("ls > /home/you/thefile");
```

Comment: I agree this is easier than fopen(), but it is not exactly the canonical example of how to write to a file in C. -1.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you write to a file, just replace your output with what you want in the file.
As the other person mentions you could just pipe it to a file.

```
FILE *ofp;
char outputFilename[] = "out.txt";

ofp = fopen(outputFilename, "w");

if (ofp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file %s!\n",
          outputFilename);
  exit(1);
}

fprintf(ofp, "ls");
fclose(ofp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a another function to redirect stdout to a file

```
###stdio.h
###FILE *freopen(const char *filename, const char *mode, FILE *stream);

    int main()
    {
      char outputFilename[] = "out.txt";
      freopen(filename, "w", stdout)

        system("ls");
        return 0;
    }
```

All the output to stdout after redirecting will be written to file "out.txt"